# What does 'language' mean in Political Philosophy?

Tags: reference-request, political-philosophy, critical-theory

> This practical and critical objective is achieved in two steps. The first is a critical survey of the **languages** and practices in which the struggles arise, and various theoretical solutions are proposed and implemented as reforms.
> Source: [James Tully, Political Philosophy as A Critical Activity](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/251772654_Political_Philosophy_As_a_Critical_Activity)

1. What does James Tully mean when speaking of language in this context? After reading the pages that follow, it seems it is related to Critical Theory, the Doll House Play, Foucault and Wittgenstein (analytical philosophy?).
2. Would you also provide links to articles that further elaborate on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By "languages" he does not mean anything specific to political philosophy or this context, just the vocabulary in which problems, "struggles" and solutions are articulated. One can similarly talk about languages and practices in which, say, geometric problems are formulated, struggled with and solved. Of course, the vocabularies used are radically different, and he is applying Wittgensteinian and other methods to explicate the relevant use.

Comment: @Conifold would you recommend accessible reading to understand this Wittgensteinian method?

Comment: You can try [Shawver's commentary](https://postmoderntherapies.com/word.html) and [Peters's review](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00131857.2020.1821190) to get the idea. [Wittgenstein: Key Concepts by Jolley](https://ndpr.nd.edu/reviews/wittgenstein-key-concept/) is a fairly accessible book.